# algebras for endofunctors vs monads and free monads

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monads

I have a question concerning proposition 10.14 from [Steve Awodey's lecture notes](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/80-413-713/notes/chap10.pdf) (PDF) concerning the relationship between algebras for endofunctors and algebras for monads. Specifically, the proposition states that the following are equivalent for an endofunctor $P : \mathbf{S} \to \mathbf{S}$:

- There is a categorical equivalence $\text{Alg}(P) \cong \text{Alg}(T)$ for a *monad* $T : \mathbf{S} \to \mathbf{S}$
- The forgetful functor $U : \text{Alg}(P) \to \mathbf{S}$ has a left adjoint
- For each $A \in \mathbf{S}$, the endofunctor $P_A : X \mapsto A + P(X)$ has an initial algebra.

Implicit in the theorem (or detailed in the proof, I believe) is that:

- The monad $T = UF$ if $F$ is the left adjoint.
- The action of $T$ takes an object $A$ to the initial algebra of the endofunctor $P_A$ mentioned in the third point above, which is the "free algebra on $A$" ("free monads are initial algebras")

Unfortunately I have trouble following this theorem through for the example of monoids.
Specifically, let $P(X) = 1 + X^2$ (work over $\mathbf{S} = \mathbf{Set}$ for simplicity).
An algebra for $P$ is a monoid structure on a set.
The associated monad $T$ should be (I think), the "list" or "free monoid" functor $TA = A^*$, the monad whose algebras are traditionally recognized as monoids.
I have two questions:

- I do not see how $T$ defined by $TA = A^*$ is the initial algebra for $P_A$, which maps $A \mapsto 1 + P(X) = A + (1 + X^2)$, i.e. how $A^*$ the least fixed point/solution to $X = A + (1 + X^2)$. It seems instead that $A^*$ is the solution to $X = 1 + A \times X$.
- It is my impression that $\text{Alg}(P)$ contains sets with monoid structure that are, in particular, not even monoids, whereas $\text{Alg}(T)$ imposes more restrictions (algebra arrows must be compatible with the unit and multiplication of the monoid) that actually restrict such maps to be proper monoids (e.g., associative, and that the unit acts like a unit) So how can we have the equivalence $\text{Alg}(P) \cong \text{Alg}(T)$?

Comment: No, $T$ is not the list monad. As you say, the list monad has algebras which are monoids, and we are looking for a monad whose algebras are $P$-algebras.

Comment: (Functor) algebras of $1 + -^2$ are not monoids. They are pointed magmas, and the initial algebra contains unlabeled binary trees. The problem is that you used only the generators from the usual algebraic presentation of monoids, but not the equations. With the equations the $1$ part becomes a unit and the $^2$ part is associative, so it becomes equivalent to the right-associated lists you're familiar with.

Comment: I see. It makes sense that this construction could not "magically" add equational information. My goal in reading this was to understand how I could express algebraic structures with a "simpler" functor than the "term algebra functor", e.g. a polynomial functor that just expresses the signature (similar to how coalgebras are often just described as coalgebras over a simple polynomial functor). 
From this point of view it seems odd that algebras over the list monad do somehow incorporate "equational information". Is there no simple (e.g. polynomial) functor that would capture proper monoids?

Comment: I don't think so. That is the reason for monad algebras. Equations arise from the algebra action having to commute with the unit and multiplication of the monad. In the case of free monads, the equations force algebras to be equivalent to a functor algebra, since although the free monad is like $\coprod_n F^n$, the action $\coprod_n F^nA →A$ has to be robust under ways of splitting up $n$, such that the only thing it can do is repeatedly apply an $FA → A$ action.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments. Upon further reflection, I see my mistake was expecting $T$ to be the "free monoid" functor in the usual sense - meaning relative to the variety of monoids. Instead it is the "absolutely free monoid" functor that just constructs the term algebra on a monoid signature. With that everything makes more sense!